# Why did Siri stop responding to "Hey Siri" on iPhone X iOS 12.3.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Since late March/early April of 2019, which means since iOS 12.2 through 12.3.1 Siri stop responding to "Hey Siri" on my iPhone X. I purchased the iPhone new in January 2018, and it has incurred any damage or misuse.

Sometime in 2017, I began to use "Hey Siri" to do things like play songs from a playlist, call the family, get directions to a new contact's residence, etc. The reason is that I often do not have a free hand to access the phone because I am a parent to a special needs child, and "Hey Siri" was very helpful.

Now I am frustrated, because:

The only way I can access Siri is via the sidebar.

I have reset the phone more than once, Siri still does not work.

I have turned off Siri and turned it back on, no change.

Do any of you have even any suggestions on how I might troubleshoot and get Siri to respond to "Hey Siri?"

[image: Siri is activated and even Listen for "Hey Siri"]

Comment: Is there any audio accessory connected/paired over Bluetooth to your iPhone?

Comment: Did you make sure that 'Hey Siri' is turned on in Settings?  Can you post a screenshot of that page?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207489 This has all the troubleshooting we all might ask in comments.

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes but they have been the same since last year.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii already went there and tried all the suggestions, nothing worked.

Comment: Can you turn it off and add again your "Hey Siri" phrase? Restarting the iPhone is a generic solution though. Also the article in some places recommends contacting Apple Support. It would be tiring I guess.

Comment: @ankiiiiiiiI have turned it off back on, reset it, and turned off siri. All that along with having to repeat phrases several different times to set up siri. It is very tiring and the Apple store is not along the route of my daily travels.

Comment: @ankiiiiiiiiiii, even have gone as far as completely resetting my phone and making it as if it was new, as recently as the second to the last day of December 2019 and hey siri, still does not work...